# Installing Managed Package with InstalledPackage

Tags: managed-package, lma

I have a (free) managed package on the AppExchange. It is not an extension package, but it bundles nicely with a few other free packages. In order to help users get started, I tested out a Metadata API solution that would install my package and these other free packages using the `InstalledPackage` metadata type.

This works totally fine, and installs all the packages in the test org in one go. I'm pretty happy with how it works (Trialforce just isn't a great option in my case).

However, no new lead in the LMA is created for me! I don't use licenses, but I imagine no license would be created too...

This is a two part question:

1) how can I know about installs of my package done via `InstalledPackage` deployments?

2) if I were to release a paid app, would people be able to install my package for free with this trick?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simpler than I expected. My package (in the LMA) has a "Refresh Licenses" button. On clicking it, it created the missing Lead and License object! This just means I need to get in the habit of refreshing licenses more.

[image: LMA Screenshot]